# Why am I getting this error:"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control lbFolders accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

This is baffling me, maybe somebody can shine the light of education on my ignorance.  This is in a C# windows app. I am  accessing the contents of a listbox from a thread.  When I try to access it like this

```
prgAll.Maximum = lbFolders.SelectedItems.Count;
```

I get the error.  However, here is the part I don't get.  If I comment out that line, the very next line

```
foreach (string dir in lbFolders.SelectedItems)
```

executes just fine.

Edit:
As usual, my communication skills are lacking.  Let me clarify.

I know that accessing GUI items from threads other than the ones they were created on causes problems.  I know the right way to access them is via delegate.

My question was mainly this:
Why can I access and iterate through the SelectedItems object just fine, but when I try to get (not set) the Count property of it, it blows up.

Comment: Most answers here are correct, yet you say they're wrong because they don't work for you, and likely you are the one who voted them down. This got you my downvote.

Comment: If you hover over the upvote or the downvote button, you will see that it says "This was helpful" or "This was not helpful"  Simply telling me that I can't do something which I can do is NOT helpful. Not to mention that it doesn't actually address the question I asked.

Comment: As for how you voted my question, I could care less.

Comment: The thing is that they all explained the simple rule: Don't do cross-thread GUI stuff, because that is the reason for the error. The only question you asked is "Why am I getting this error", and they all explained why. You did not exactly ask why you are not getting that error in certain situations.

Comment: @"I could care less": Fine, but I like to know why I was voted down. And because of that, I always write why I am voting someone else down. Call it good manners.

Comment: "You did not exactly ask why you are not getting that error in certain situations" <br>
Then what would this be:  However, here is the part I don't get. If I comment out that line, the very next lineforeach (string dir in lbFolders.SelectedItems)executes just fine.

Comment: @Kevin - accessing prgAll.Maximum and lbFolders.SelectedItems.Count are both operations that cannot be performed from other threads. Enumerating through SelectedItems is apparently OK. However, that doesn't change the fact that the first line must be invoked.

Comment: If these answers, all of which are reasonable and should lead you down the correct path, don't answer the question or don't work, follow up with more details about why and I'm sure we'll be able to help.  Invoke to get back to gui thread should work for you, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
prgAll.Maximum = lbFolders.SelectedItems.Count;
```

On that line you perform an assignment (**set/add**), which by default is not thread-safe.

On the second line it's just a **get** operation, where thread-safety merely doesn't matter.

EDIT: I don't mean access to the prgAll element.

Accessing the Count property **changes the internal state** of the ListBox inner collection, that is why it throws the exception.

Comment: nope, wrong answer. I broke it up and the error is happening when getting the Count value, not when setting the Maximum value

Comment: +1 for the remark about inner state. Unfortunately Kevin doesn't like your answer, even though it's true.

Comment: Actually, his edited answer makes much more sense. Changed my -1 to a +1

Comment: Of course, why M$ designed it like that still doesn't make sense, but that isn't Lykathea's problem

Comment: I think the reason is that they only test for inter-thread calls when it really matters. Kind of an optimization.

Answer (score 21):

You can't access GUI elements from a separate thread.  Use a delegate to make the change.

eg.

```
lblStatus.Invoke((Action)(() => lblStatus.Text = counter.ToString()));
```

or older skool:

```
lblTest.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(delegate() 
{ 
  lblTest.Text = i.ToString(); 
}));
```

I've got a blog post on how to do this in all the .Net releases [here](http://rumandcode.wordpress.com/2008/07/17/doing-invokes-on-winform-controls-examples-from-delegates-to-lambdas/).

Answer (score 3):

The Count property of SelectedItems is not thread-safe, so you can't use it cross-thread.

Comment: Thank you, this is the only answer which even begins to answer the question.  So, the SelectedItems object is thread-safe, but its property isn't?  That doesn't make sense to me.  Not saying you are wrong, just that it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Regardless of it making sense or not, its clear that cross-threading is the issue and you should be invoking back to the gui thread to access those properties.  To see if something is thread-safe, look it up in the MSDN library - it clearly states thread-safety.

Comment: I actually did look up both the SelectedItems object and the Count property on MSDN, I didn't see anything on the "thread-safeness" of either.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to write to a control from a thread other than the main thread. Use Invoke or BeginInvoke.

```
void SetMax()
{
    if (prgAll.InvokeRequired)
    {
        prgAll.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(SetMax));
        return;
    }

    prgAll.Maximum = lbFolders.SelectedItems.Count;
}
```

Comment: nope, wrong answer.  I broke it up and the error is happening when getting the Count value, not when setting the Maximum value

Comment: @Kevin Any chance you're creating prgAll and lblFolders from different threads?

Comment: @Kevin using prgAll.Invoke instead of this.Invoke might make that work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't touch a GUI object from a thread that isn't the main GUI thread. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the) for more details and the solution.

Comment: OOpps, sorry, didn't mean to remove your comment

Comment: No problem, I'll just re-add it. Your answer doesn't make sense because setting the value of the prgAll.Maximum isn't blowing up, neither does it blow up on accessing the SelectItems itself, just on the selecteditems.count

Comment: @Kevin: matt's answer makes perfect sense. While you can't generally access GUI elements from another thread, not all properties or methods suffer from this. The rule is quite simple: Don't touch GUI objects in a thread other than the GUI thread. See Echostorms answer for how to do it right.

Comment: @OregonGhost: no, your answer makes sense, at least more sense. His doesn't make sense because he's telling me I can't do something which I obviously can.

Comment: @OregonGhost.  However, it still doesn't make sense to me that I can access ListBox.selecteditems and iterate through it with no problem, but if I try to access ListBox.SelectedItems.Count, it blows up.

Comment: @Kevin: Lykathea explains why this is the way it is. Maybe you could implement it in another way, but that's how the .NET team did it. Just never access any GUI elements from another thread and you're fine.

Comment: I think it goes back to a Win32 issue (or design decision), which is still there in WinForms because it uses Win32/MFC under the hood

Answer (score 1):

Because you created a control in a thread and you're trying to reach it from another one. Call the [InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) property as shown here:

```
private void RunMe()
{
    if (!InvokeRequired)
    {
        myLabel.Text = "You pushed the button!";
    }
    else
    {
        Invoke(new ThreadStart(RunMe));
    }
}
```

Comment: This gave me "No overload for 'function name' matches delegate 'System.Threading.ThreadStart'

Comment: This post has helped: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20081/Getting-Around-InvokeRequired-Without-Copy-and-Pas

 but it doesn't explain how to call a function with parameters. My 'RunMe' function has two parameters and writing the delegate without them throws 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException'

Adding them as part of the delegate gives the compiler error: 'Method Name Expected'

Comment: Figured it out! You add a second parameter to invoke to pass your arguments. Like this: this.BeginInvoke(new DoThreadedGoodManualType(DoThreadedGoodManual), new Object[] {param1, param2};));

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private delegate void xThreadCallBack();
private void ThreadCallBack()
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new xThreadCallBack(ThreadCallBack));
    }
    else
    {
        //do what you want
    }
}
```

Though, the answer with the lambda expression would suffice.