# Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I getting this error:“Cross-thread operation not valid: Control lbFolders accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244591/why-am-i-getting-this-errorcross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-lbfolders)

I am new in winforms.In my code I am updating progress bar with for loop and now I need to update a Label in the form the loop count as shown below -

> public partial class Form1 : Form
>       {
>           public Form1()
>           {
>               InitializeComponent();
>
> ```
>         Shown += new EventHandler(Form1_Shown);
>
>         // To report progress from the background worker we need to set this property
>         backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
>         // This event will be raised on the worker thread when the worker starts
>         backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
>         // This event will be raised when we call ReportProgress
>         backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
>     }
>
>     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>
>     }
>
>     void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         // Start the background worker
>         backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
>     }
>
>
>     // On worker thread so do our thing!
>     void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
>     {
>         // Your background task goes here
>         for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
>         {
>             label1.Text = "Trade" + i;
>             // Report progress to 'UI' thread
>             backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
>             // Simulate long task
>             System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
>         }
>     }
>     // Back on the 'UI' thread so we can update the progress bar
>     void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         // The progress percentage is a property of e
>         progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

but while accessing label1,it is throwing error -

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label1' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on.

How can I update text of label1

Comment: When posting code, you should use the `{}` button, not the `"` quote button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cross-thread+operation+not+valid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update your label in your progress handler instead of inside the worker thread.

```
// On worker thread so do our thing! 
 void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
 { 
     // Your background task goes here 
     for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
     { 
         // Report progress to 'UI' thread 
         backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i); 
         // Simulate long task 
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); 
     } 
 } 
 // Back on the 'UI' thread so we can update the progress bar - and our label :)
 void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) 
 { 
     // The progress percentage is a property of e 
     progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; 
     label1.Text = String.Format("Trade{0}",e.ProgressPercentage);
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can only access the control from the thread where it was created(that is, the UI thread). In other threads(like your BackgroundWorker), you need to use [Control.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx).

```
label1.BeginInvoke(delegate { label1.Text = "Trade" + i; });
```

Comment: The label is used to report the progress of the worker thread, so it should be updated in the progress handler. BeginInvoke is not recommanded in that case.

Comment: Needed to cast the delegate to (Action) but otherwise works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` runs on a separate thread from the main UI thread.

So when you call:

```
label1.Text = "Trade" + i;
```

inside backgroundWorker1_DoWork your application will throw the Cross-thread exception, because you're reporting the progress of your worker you can update the label1.Text value in the `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` method